# How do I solve the System.NullReferenceException error

Tags: c#, nullreferenceexception

I just try to create one of WCF to get all client details. When I try to run that WCF which get data from SP its show this error:

[image: service error]

Caught exception:

[image: caught exception]

And also when put break point that time I see the ID is coming but still error showing same.

Class code:

```
public class CommanCall
{
    string Connection = "Data Source=USER-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=BlueEyeNewDatabase;Integrated Security=True";

    public List<Client> SelectAllClient(int id)
    {
        List<Client> ClientList = new List<Client>();
        using (var Context = new EmpSystemContext(Connection))
        {
            var DbResult = Context.SelectClientDetails(id);
            if (DbResult != null)
            {
                foreach (var Row in DbResult)
                {   
                    Client clist = new Client
                    {
                        ClientName = Row.ClientName,
                        ClientAddress = Row.ClientAddress,
                        PreferredCurrency = Row.PreferredCurrency,
                        FirstName = Row.FirstName,
                        LastName = Row.LastName,
                        City = Row.City,
                        State = Row.State,
                        Country = Row.Country,
                        PostalCode = Row.PostalCode,
                        ContactName = Row.ContactName,
                        ContactNumber = Row.ContactNumber,
                        Email = Row.Email,
                        ContactEmail = Row.ContactEmail
                    };
                    ClientList.Add(clist);
                }
            }
        }                      
       return ClientList;
   }
}
```

Service.svc.cs

```
public class Service1 : IService1
{
    public static EmpSystem.Domain.CommanCall Comman;

    public ListResponce<Client> GetAllClientDetailsById(int id)
    {
        ListResponce<Client> lstclientResp = new ListResponce<Client>();
        lstclientResp.Message = "Taru kai na thai ek record find na thayo";
        lstclientResp.Success = false;
        int id1 = id;
        List<Client> lstclient = Comman.SelectAllClient(id);
        lstclientResp.Result = lstclient;
        if(lstclient!=null)
        {
            lstclientResp.Message = "Congo hahahhah Record Find thaya";
            lstclientResp.Success = true;
        }
        return new ListResponce<Client>
        {
            Message = lstclientResp.Message,
            Success = lstclientResp.Success,
            Result = lstclientResp.Result
        };           
    }      
}
```

IService file

```
public interface IService1
{
    [OperationContract]
    [System.ServiceModel.Web.WebInvoke(Method = "GET", ResponseFormat = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle = System.ServiceModel.Web.WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
    ListResponce<Client> GetAllClientDetailsById(int id);
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the code you posted I can suggest you forgot to create an instance of `CommanCall`. Field `Comman` is reference type which is by default initialized with `null`. So `NullReferenceException` thrown when you trying to call member of `null`. Create an instance for `Comman`, for example:

```
public static EmpSystem.Domain.CommanCall Comman = new EmpSystem.Domain.CommanCall();
```

If field `Comman` initialized somewhere else, please, show stack trace of exception you caught.